# Find items not listed using three table master sku table,sold,not sold

Tags: mysql

We ave three tables
**Mastersku Table** which has all the SKU's
**Sold Table**: has all the SKU's which had at least 1 qty sale along with the portal name in which it has been sold
**Not sold Table**: has SKU's which are  listed on the portal but not sold along with the portal name

Need SKU's list from Mastersku with a column which says sold, notsold, notlisted. *an SKU which is not present in both sold and not sold tables would be considered as not listed* my code is below guess need to join it with Mastersku where the field name is SKU and in the other two tables it is `Trim Sku`. Have added distinct as `Trim Sku` is duplicate in sold and not sold table.just in case SKU present in sold and notsold for a given portal means it is the wrong sold should precede. we at present move SKU's from not sold to sold manually.

```
    select DISTINCT `portal`,`Trim Sku`,'sold' TableName from sold
    UNION ALL 
    select DISTINCT `portal`,`Trim Sku`,'notsold' TableName from notsold
```

Comment: What's the difference between notsold and notlisted and how do you get a table of notsolds which doesn't include all skus not sold?

Comment: an SKU which is not present in both sold and not sold tables would be considered as not listed

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I'd left join the `mastersku` table on the other two, and use a `case` expression to understand if it's sold or not:

```sql
SELECT    m.*, 
          CASE WHEN s.`trim sku` IS NOT NULL THEN 'sold'
               WHEN n.`trim sku` IS NOT NULL THNE 'not sold'
               ELSE 'not listed'
          END AS status
FROM      mastersku m
LEFT JOIN sold      s ON m.`sku` = s.`trim sku`
LEFT JOIN notsold   n ON m.`sku` = n.`trim sku`
```

Comment: `trim sku` has duplicates in both the tables (sold ,not sold) we need distinct from each table and then join

Comment: @Kanted please share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it.